# How to use pgRouting (pgr_drivingDistance) with GTFS?

Tags: pgrouting, postgis-2.0, general-transit-feed-specification

I used gtfs2pgrouting to import gtfs data in postgresql, then I have these tables

```
List of relations
 Schema |    Name     | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------------+-------+----------
 gtfs   | agency      | table | postgres
 gtfs   | calendar    | table | postgres
 gtfs   | frequencies | table | postgres
 gtfs   | routes      | table | postgres
 gtfs   | shapes      | table | postgres
 gtfs   | stop_times  | table | postgres
 gtfs   | stops       | table | postgres
 gtfs   | trips       | table | postgres
(8 rows)
```

(several tables as "shapes" are empty)

But is it possible to use pgr_drivingDistance on this or is it another way to do it? My goal is to create isochrones

Thanks

Comment: no idea what gtfs is but pgRouting uses dijksra so if you network topology (routes table) you should be able to use assign_vertex_id(...) to create node/edge colums/tables for pgr_drivingDistance.

Comment: the problem is that there is no table for edges, only nodes. Routes is another thing [link](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference?hl=fr#routes_fields)

Comment: I'm working on the same problem. One thing you can do is download osm data and create a topology. Then use POSTGIS <-> operator to find the nearest node and work from there.